# Writing string to specific dir using chaquopy 4.0.0

Tags: chaquopy

I am trying a proof of concept here: 
Using Chaquopy 4.0.0 (I use python 2.7.15), I am trying to write a string to file in a specific folder (getFilesDir()) using Python, then reading in via Android.

To check whether the file was written, I am checking for the file's length (see code below).

I am expecting to get any length latger than 0 (to verify that the file indeed has been written to the specific location), but I keep getting 0.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

main.py:

```py
import os.path
save_path = "/data/user/0/$packageName/files/"
name_of_file = raw_input("test")
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")
file1 = open(completeName, "w")
toFile = raw_input("testAsWell")
file1.write(toFile)
file1.close()
```

OnCreate:

````java
if (! Python.isStarted()) {
    Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "test.txt");
    Log.e("TEST", String.valueOf(file.length()));
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you've based your app on the [console example](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy-console), so I'll give an answer for both cases.

If you **have** based your app on the console example, then the code in `onCreate` will run before the code in `main.py`, and the file won't exist the first time you start the activity. It should exist the second time: if it still doesn't, try using the [Android Studio file explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer) to see what's in the files directory.

If you **haven't** based your app on the console example, then you'll need to execute `main.py` manually, like this:

```
Python.getInstance().getModule("main");
```

Also, without the input UI which the console example provides, you won't be able to read anything from stdin. So you'll need to do one of the following:

- Base your app on the console example; or
- Replace the `raw_input` calls with a hard-coded file name and content; or
- Create a normal Android UI with a text box or something, and get input from the user that way.

Comment: I have tried to use the console example just for ease of use, however eventually I'd like to use the code on my native Android app. removing raw_input did the job, so the code works on the console example, however I can't seem to get the main.py file to run. I've taken care of all the requirements, and my onCreate looks like this: if (! Python.isStarted()) {
            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));
            Python.getInstance().getModule("main");
        }

Comment: Try adding some `print` calls to the Python code so you can see whether it's actually being executed from beginning to end. Python stdout and stderr should go to the logcat.

Comment: If `main.py` is being executed but you still can't find the file, then double-check the file location. Instead of hard-coding the path, you can use `Python.getPlatform().getApplication().getFilesDir()`, which should be more portable to other devices.

Comment: Sweet, that's actually quite the lifesaver!